# org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Unterminated string literal

Tags: java, postgresql, jsp

I should print ten questions of a questionnaire only that comes to the third question and it stops and gives me this error. What can be the cause?

> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Unterminated string literal started at position 150 in SQL 
>   SELECT * FROM domandarisposta WHERE domandachiusa='Dove si trova l'Estonia?' AND insegnamento='geografia' AND dataprova='12-12-12' AND docente='Buffon'

Comment: The apostrophe in "l'Estonia" is breaking the string.  You need to escape it.

Comment: occurs when missing completion single quote/extra one for string in query

Answer (score 7):

Look at "l'Estonia?" I can't tell for sure, but that looks like an apostrophe in the value.

I suggest using a PreparedStatement with variables. The variable values don't have to be checked for apostrophes or other punctuation. BTW, providing a value with punctuation is a means of launching a SQL injection attack.